# How to transition a responsive navbar and change the icon to X?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I am trying to add a transition when the `nav.items` comes down.
I tried `transition: height 3s;` in `nav.items` but it didnt work.

How can I make the icon change to `X` when we click it?
The code I tried is:

```
menu.innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-x" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
       <path d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/>
     </svg>'
```

But it again didn't work. I would appreciate if anyone would help :))
Here's the full code snippet:

```js
const menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0]
const navItem0 = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item')[0]
const navItem1 = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item')[1]
const navItem2 = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item')[2]
const navItem3 = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item')[3]
const navItem4 = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item')[4]

/*  
IMPORTANT!
let array = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        array.push("navItem"+i)
        eval('navItem' + i + ' = ' + 'document' + '.' + 'getElementsByClassName' + "('nav-item')" + [i] + ';');
        console.log(navItem0)
}       
*/
menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navItem0.classList.toggle('responsive-li')
  navItem1.classList.toggle('responsive-li')
  navItem2.classList.toggle('responsive-li')
  navItem3.classList.toggle('responsive-li')
  navItem4.classList.toggle('responsive-li')
  /*      menu.innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-x" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/>
      </svg>' */
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #222;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 16px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%) !important;
  padding: 25px 35px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.nav-ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-item {
  margin: 0px 30px;
  transition: height 300ms linear;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.responsive-li {
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 890px) {
  .navbar{
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .divider {
    display: none;
  }

  .logo {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }

  .nav-item {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .menu {
    display: block;
  }

  .nav-link{
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .nav-item {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .logo-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; /* Align the logo and icon in same row */
    width: 100%; /* Setting full width */
    justify-content: space-between; /* Fill the space between logo and icon with blank space*/
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="logo-container">
          <div class="logo">Logo</div>
          <a class="menu">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="45" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-list"
              viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                d="M2.5 12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z" />
            </svg>
          </a>
      </div>
        <ul class="nav-ul">
         <li class="nav-item">
             <form action="">
             <input type="text">
             <button class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
         </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Home</a></li>
          <hr class="divider">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Services</a></li>
          <hr class="divider">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a></li>
          <hr class="divider">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have the transition set on height, but you aren't changing the height - the element is either shown or not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use JQuery function called slideToggle() for sliding down the menu content. Its easy and effective.
Find it [here](https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) or you can add this,

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.menu').click(function(){
   $('.nav-ul').slideToggle(1000);
  });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: OP is not using jQuery.